# Is this the correct way of calculating the median?

Tags: statistics, median

I just completed the June $2009$ mei stats paper. On the mark scheme for question $5ii$ it shows the median being calculated using $600$, shouldn't it be $600+1$?

I thought the median was calculated using $(n+1/2)$.

Can anyone clarify this for me?

question $5ii$
link to paper:
http://www.mei.org.uk/files/papers/s109ju_n3z8.pdf

Comment: It would be easier to discuss this is you had shown the acceptable answer(s). In particular is is not clear how you decided it is using 600 instead of 601. The only thing for sure is that the median (by any of the usual definitions) must lie somewhere in $[50, 100)$. Interpolation to 'estimate' a value within that interval relies on unstated assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

There are $1200$ observations so both the value at the $600$th ordered value and at the $601$st could be taken as the median from its definition, or anything in between. Using a $\frac{n+1}{2}$ approach might suggest the average of the $600$th and the $601$st ordered values.

The mark scheme should have allowed for any of these interpretations in the interpolation so anything like $80$ or $80.125$ or $80.0625$ or rounded versions of these should have gained the mark.